# What are the units in the heat equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, units, thermal-conductivity

If we write the heat equation as:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u-\alpha \nabla \cdot (\nabla u) = f
$$

Then,

1. Temperature of the material: $u: m^3\times s\rightarrow K$
2. Thermal diffusivity: $\alpha : m^3\rightarrow m^2/s$
3. Heat source: $f : m^3\times s \rightarrow K/s$

Basically, we map a point in time and space to some quantity.  Now, when we apply a finite element method to solve the heat equation, sometimes we move the material properties inside of the divergence and write the equation as:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u-\nabla \cdot (\alpha \nabla u) = f
$$

In this case, I don't know what the quantity $\alpha$ means, nor what its units are.

---

## Edit 1

In case there was some confusion, I come from an applied math background, and since $u$, $\alpha$, and $f$ are functions I tend to label their domains as well hence the $m^3\times s$ bit.  Basically, that's my way of saying that the temperature varies with respect to space and time.  In any case, based on the responses, here's everything rewritten using @kyle-kanos 's response

$$
\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u}_{\cfrac{K}{s}}-\underbrace{\underbrace{\alpha}_{\cfrac{m^2}{s}} \underbrace{\nabla \cdot (\underbrace{\nabla \underbrace{u}_K)}_{\cfrac{K}{m}}}_{\cfrac{K}{m^2}}}_{\cfrac{K}{s}} = \underbrace{f}_{\cfrac{K}{s}}
$$

Then, if we rewrite the equation as

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u-\nabla \cdot (\alpha \nabla u) = f
$$

we can expand this to

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u-\alpha\nabla \cdot (\nabla u)-\nabla\alpha\cdot\nabla u = f
$$

which is what we had before plus one new term.  Hence

$$
\underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}u}_{\cfrac{K}{s}}-\underbrace{\underbrace{\alpha}_{\cfrac{m^2}{s}} \underbrace{\nabla \cdot (\underbrace{\nabla \underbrace{u}_K)}_{\cfrac{K}{m}}}_{\cfrac{K}{m^2}}}_{\cfrac{K}{s}} -\underbrace{\underbrace{\nabla\underbrace{\alpha}_{\cfrac{m^2}{s}}}_{\cfrac{m}{s}}\cdot\underbrace{\nabla \underbrace{u}_{K}}_{\cfrac{K}{m}}}_{\cfrac{K}{s}} = \underbrace{f}_{\cfrac{K}{s}}
$$

Of course, this only really matters if $\alpha$ varies spatially otherwise $\nabla \alpha=0$.  In other words, $\alpha$ is still the thermal diffusivity.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: The units haven't changed at all, you still have the same quantities with the same number of derivatives in each term. If we expand the outer divergence, then you'll find that this gives you the original heat equation plus a new term proportional to $\nabla \alpha \cdot \nabla u$. This is zero in the heat equation because $\alpha$ is a constant, so this is a new contribution representing a spatially dependent thermal diffusivity. I am not as familiar with finite elements but I think that unnatural terms like this are sometimes added to improve convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The units for $u$ should be $K$, $m$ and $s$ aren't involved here. The partial derivatives introduce the factor of $T$ and $L$, so it should read, in terms of the units,
$$
\frac Ks+\frac{m^2}{s}\cdot\frac{1}{m}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{m} \cdot K\right)=\frac Ks\tag{1}
$$
which all the terms in the middle reduce to $K/s$.

Moving the $\alpha$ to inside the divergence operator does not actually change the units, it is still $m/s$. You can verify this by writing (1) as
$$
\frac Ks+\cdot\frac{1}{m}\cdot\left(\left[\alpha\right]\cdot\frac{1}{m} \cdot K\right)=\frac Ks\tag{1}
$$
which can only be satisfied by $\left[\alpha\right]=m^2/s$.

What *does* change is in the first equation, $\alpha$ is a constant whereas in the second equation, it can be spatially-dependent, $\alpha=\alpha(\mathbf x)$, such that $\nabla\alpha\cdot\nabla u\neq0$.